# CSS Background-image won't display

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have some issues with css image background, will only display if i use the live server extension from VS Code but when I try to open it by double clicking it or upload it on my hosting won't show up...and I am a bit stuck..

the image is located in C:\Users\new01\OneDrive\Desktop\Site constructor\EcoFarm\img
the index.html is located in EcoFarm

here is the code

```
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-content">
            <h1>Eco Farm - Home</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            <button class="discover">Discover</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.banner{
    background: url(/img/banner.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: calc(80vh - 80px);
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-content{
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.banner h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
    padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;
}
.banner p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.discover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 40px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color:#75D442;
    border-style: solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.discover:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me the files structure and where do you have your image?

Comment: C:\Users\new01\OneDrive\Desktop\Site constructor\EcoFarm\img 
index.html is in EcoFarm

Comment: and where are the css files?

Comment: in EcoFarm also I noticed when I inspect element I receive an error in console "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: remove the first / in background: url(/img/banner.jpg); make it background: url(img/banner.jpg);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your height property isn't giving a proper value, which is what's breaking the background property. having a height of 100% doesn't actually give the div a real height, instead it says "take up 100% of the parent's height." Since the parent container is the body, in this case, you have to give the parent container a height value.

So, you can do one of two things. Either give the parent container a height value (100vh, 100px, 10em, etc.), or give the banner a height value. See below

```css
/* Option one: 
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
*/

.banner{
    background-image: url('https://www.imgacademy.com/sites/default/files/legacyhotel.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px); /* option 2 */
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-content{
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.banner h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
    padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;
}
.banner p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.discover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 40px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color:#75D442;
    border-style: solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.discover:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-content">
            <h1>Eco Farm - Home</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            <button class="discover">Discover</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I changed the percent to vh still won't show

Comment: @GGBaal then I suspect the issue is with the linked file. You'll notice in my example that I used a random image I found online, obviously because I don't have the same image as you do. Try uploading the image somewhere like imgur, rightclick then copy image link and paste that link into ```background-image: url('here');```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have to go to .banner in you css code and fix (background:url(image)) to (background-image: url("./image-link-on-your-folder-project") ),

```css
.banner{
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: calc(80vh - 80px);
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-content{
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.banner h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
    padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;
}
.banner p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.discover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 40px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color:#75D442;
    border-style: solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.discover:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-content">
            <h1>Eco Farm - Home</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            <button class="discover">Discover</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`enter code here`